# How to generate unique GUID 36 chars in SQLITE iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

I am trying to create a table which is unique and has primary key. I know in sqlite we can develop Unique AUTOINCREMENT ID [SQL AUTOINCREMENT](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html), but is it possible to generate Unique GUID which is 36 chars long. The only reason to do that is to make it more unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the bit of code I use for UUIDs (I may have even found it here on Stack Overflow)...

```
+ (NSString *)GetUUID
{
    CFUUIDRef theUUID = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
    CFStringRef string = CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, theUUID);
    CFRelease(theUUID);
    return [(NSString *)string autorelease];
}
```

I don't know how long the UUIDs generated are because in the ways I use it I don't care so perhaps check that by passing the result into a `NSLog` call.

HTH, Pedro :)

Answer (score 0):

I user this code to generate guids on the iphone - category on NSString.  Can't remember where I found it, but it works great.

```
#import "NSString_UniqueID.h"


static unichar x (unsigned int); 

@implementation NSString (TWUUID) 

+ (NSString*) stringWithUniqueId 
{ 
    CFUUIDRef uuid = CFUUIDCreate(NULL); 
    CFUUIDBytes b = CFUUIDGetUUIDBytes(uuid); 
    unichar unichars[22]; 
    unichar* c = unichars; 
    *c++ = x(b.byte0 >> 2); 
    *c++ = x((b.byte0 & 3 << 4) + (b.byte1 >> 4)); 
    *c++ = x((b.byte1 & 15 << 2) + (b.byte2 >> 6)); 
    *c++ = x(b.byte2 & 63); 
    *c++ = x(b.byte3 >> 2); 
    *c++ = x((b.byte3 & 3 << 4) + (b.byte4 >> 4)); 
    *c++ = x((b.byte4 & 15 << 2) + (b.byte5 >> 6)); 
    *c++ = x(b.byte5 & 63); 
    *c++ = x(b.byte6 >> 2); 
    *c++ = x((b.byte6 & 3 << 4) + (b.byte7 >> 4)); 
    *c++ = x((b.byte7 & 15 << 2) + (b.byte8 >> 6)); 
    *c++ = x(b.byte8 & 63); 
    *c++ = x(b.byte9 >> 2); 
    *c++ = x((b.byte9 & 3 << 4) + (b.byte10 >> 4)); 
    *c++ = x((b.byte10 & 15 << 2) + (b.byte11 >> 6)); 
    *c++ = x(b.byte11 & 63); 
    *c++ = x(b.byte12 >> 2); 
    *c++ = x((b.byte12 & 3 << 4) + (b.byte13 >> 4)); 
    *c++ = x((b.byte13 & 15 << 2) + (b.byte14 >> 6)); 
    *c++ = x(b.byte14 & 63); 
    *c++ = x(b.byte15 >> 2); 
    *c = x(b.byte15 & 3); 
    CFRelease(uuid); 
    return [NSString stringWithCharacters: unichars length: 22]; 
} 
@end 
// Convert six-bit values into letters, numbers or _ or $ (64 characters in that set). 
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
unichar x (unsigned int c) 
{ 
    if (c < 26) return 'a' + c; 
    if (c < 52) return 'A' + c - 26; 
    if (c < 62) return '0' + c - 52; 
    if (c == 62) return '$'; 
    return '_'; 
}
```